# Loop over a list of strings and increment letter count in a corresponding sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, counting

I have a 2D list as follows:

```
counts = {{"A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K",
     "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, ...};
```

The first sub-list consists of a heading, and the following sub-lists contain counts, initialized at zero.

I need to loop over another list, `sequences`, that contains strings plus a heading, and access the corresponding sub-list in `counts` to increment the appropriate letter count.

For example, take a string from `sequences`:

> MKTIIALSYILCLVFAQKLPGNDNSTATLCLGHHAVPNGTIVKTITNDQIEVTNATELVQSSSTGEICDSPHQILDGKNCTLIDALLGDPQCDGFQNKKWDLFVERSKAYSNCYPYDVPDYASLRSLVASSGTLEFNNESFNWTGVTQNGTSSACIRRSKNSFFSRLNWLTHLNFKYPALNVTMPNNEQFDKLYIWGVHHPGTDKDQIFLYAQASGRITVSTKRSQQTVSPNIGSRPRVRNIPSRISIYWTIVKPGDILLINSTGNLIAPRGYFKIRSGKSSIMRSDAPIGKCNSECITPNGSIPNDKPFQNVNRITYGACPRYVKQNTLKLATGMRNVPEKQTRGIFGAIAGFIENGWEGMVDGWYGFRHQNSEGRGQAADLKSTQAAIDQINGKLNRLIGKTNEKFHQIEKEFSEVEGRIQDLEKYVEDTKIDLWSYNAELLVALENQHTIDLTDSEMNKLFEKTKKQLRENAEDMGNGCFKIYHKCDNACIGSIRNGTYDHDVYRDEALNNRFQIKGVELKSGYKDWILWISFAISCFLLCVALLGFIMWACQKGNIRCNICI

Its corresponding sub-list in `counts` would be incremented to `{31, 27, 45, 30, 18, 27, 25, 25, 42, 11, 48, 44, 37, 8, 23, 20, 41, 34, 11, 19, 25}`.

I obtained this via `StringCount[sequences[[1]], #] & /@ counts[[1]]` but am struggling to scale this code, and to make it update the sub-lists in `counts` instead of returning a new list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sequences = { "MKTIIALSYILCLVFAQKLPGNDNSTATLCLGHHAVPNGTIVKTITNDQIEVTNATELVQSSSTGEIC\
DSPHQILDGKNCTLIDALLGDPQCDGFQNKKWDLFVERSKAYSNCYPYDVPDYASLRSLVASSGTLEFNN\
ESFNWTGVTQNGTSSACIRRSKNSFFSRLNWLTHLNFKYPALNVTMPNNEQFDKLYIWGVHHPGTDKDQI\
FLYAQASGRITVSTKRSQQTVSPNIGSRPRVRNIPSRISIYWTIVKPGDILLINSTGNLIAPRGYFKIRS\
GKSSIMRSDAPIGKCNSECITPNGSIPNDKPFQNVNRITYGACPRYVKQNTLKLATGMRNVPEKQTRGIF\
GAIAGFIENGWEGMVDGWYGFRHQNSEGRGQAADLKSTQAAIDQINGKLNRLIGKTNEKFHQIEKEFSEV\
EGRIQDLEKYVEDTKIDLWSYNAELLVALENQHTIDLTDSEMNKLFEKTKKQLRENAEDMGNGCFKIYHK\
CDNACIGSIRNGTYDHDVYRDEALNNRFQIKGVELKSGYKDWILWISFAISCFLLCVALLGFIMWACQKG\
NIRCNICI"};

counts = {{"A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K",
     "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

and the code:

```
new = Values[
  (CharacterCounts /@ sequences)[[All, First@counts]]
];

counts[[2 ;;]] += new;
counts
```

> ```
> {{"A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K", "M", 
>   "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"}, {31, 27, 45, 30, 18, 27, 25, 42,
>   11, 48, 44, 37, 8, 23, 20, 41, 34, 11, 19, 25}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well!

Comment: This is also _much_ faster than kglr's solution (see my post for timing examples).

Comment: @Kuba, as kglr pointed out, there might be occurences of `Missing[AbsentKey]` in your result. Using `Lookup[CharacterCounts /@ sequences, First@counts, 0];` is not only a bit faster but also replaces the `Missing[AbsentKey]` by `0`.

Comment: @Kuba ... and `Lookup[CharacterCounts[sequences], letters, 0];` is even a further bit faster.

Comment: I ended up using `letterCounts = Lookup[CharacterCounts[sequences], letters, 0];` and borrowing from klgr `letterCountsOutput = Join[{letters}, letterCounts];
letterCountsOutput // Grid`

Comment: This is the best solution, imo, although I admit I shouldn't have structured my question to use a pre-set counts list, so that's why I added part of kglr's answer where it builds that list.

Comment: @briennakh no worries, I am glad you found something that fits your needs. Lookup looks neat indeed. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 8):

I can propose two things that speed up the letter counting tremendously:

1.) Use `ToCharacterCode` to convert your strings to packed arrays of integers.

2.) Use a compiled funcion for additive matrix assembly.

Additive assembly of each row can be obtained with this little function.

```
cAssembleRow = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {max, _Integer}},
   Block[{b},
    b = Table[0, {max}];
    Do[b[[Compile`GetElement[a, i]]]++, {i, 1, Length[a]}];
    b
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Borrowing a bit of code from kglr but cranking up the amount of strings and their length:

```
sequences = StringJoin /@ RandomChoice[Capitalize@Alphabet[], {1000, 1000}];
letters = {"A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"};
```

Here is how kglr's and Kuba's very elegant solutions perform. `lcs2a` is a modification of Kuba's code to cope with `Missing[AbsentKey]` which may occur when some of the elements of `letters` do not occur in any of the elements in `sequences` (as kglr pointed out in a comment). It is also a bit faster.

```
lcs = letters /. LetterCounts /@ sequences /. Thread[letters -> 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First
lcs2 = Values[(CharacterCounts /@ sequences)[[All, letters]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
lcs2a = Lookup[CharacterCounts[sequences], letters, 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 3.59
>
> 0.075
>
> 0.059

My version is a bit more clunky, but it does the job several times faster:

```
i0 = ToCharacterCode["A"][[1]] - 1;
letterpos = ToCharacterCode[StringJoin[letters]] - i0;

lcs3 = cAssembleRow[ToCharacterCode[sequences] - i0, 26][[All,letterpos]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0094

When all letters occur in each element of `sequences, then all results are equal:

```
lcs == lcs2 == lcs2a == lcs3
```

> True

Comment: Henrik, if some letters  have 0 count in some sequences, `Kubalcs` will have `Missing[KeyAbsent]` instead of 0; so some additional processing is needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`LetterCounts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LetterCounts.html) as follows:

```
letters = {"A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", "I", "L", 
   "K",  "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"}; 
sequences = StringJoin /@ RandomChoice[Capitalize@Alphabet[], {10, 100}];
lcs = letters /. LetterCounts /@ sequences /. Thread[letters -> 0] ;
counts = Join[{letters}, lcs];
counts // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: I like the pretty output!